# Any way to send a string between iOS to Android using Bluetooth React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth

I’m currently making an app for react native and a feature I’m trying to implement I would really like to have offline communication between two nearby devices but I am struggling to find a way to do this. I would really like this to work and Android and iOS so that they can communicate. I have been researching in Bluetooth but all I can find is BLE which from what I’ve read does not work between classic devices such as phones. All I need to send is a string of about 3-4 characters long maximum.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BLE works with phones because they can work with both Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. So does this mean I can send small strings between an iPhone and Android using BLE?

Comment: Yes, you can use BLE for your purpose

Comment: Great thanks very much

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Can you provide any link/reference on how to use BLE to send a string from iOS to Android and vice versa?

Comment: It would be the same as sending a string from iOS to iOS or Android to Android. You need to decide which side is peripheral and which is central. The peripheral advertises, the central connects to it and reads or writes the string. There are many tutorials online, like [this one](https://punchthrough.com/core-bluetooth-basics/) for iOS and [this one](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/) for Android

Comment: Great thanks for your help